# Unable to apply CompilerFilter (lessc {infile} {outfile})

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use "less" in python django  but I am getting the following error

```
    COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (('text/less', 'lessc {infile} {outfile}'),)
    COMPRESS_OFFLINE_CONTEXT = {'STATIC_URL': 'STATIC_URL',}
    COMPRESS_CSS_FILTERS = ['compressor.filters.css_default.CssAbsoluteFilter', 'compressor.filters.cssmin.CSSMinFilter']
    COMPRESS_JS_FILTERS = ['compressor.filters.jsmin.JSMinFilter']
    COMPRESS_REBUILD_TIMEOUT = 5400
    query_cache_type = 0
    CACHALOT_ENABLED = True
    CACHALOT_CACHE_RANDOM = True
```

[image]

Comment: `npm install -g less`
and
`pip install django_compressor`

Comment: I installed the above packages but still getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by installing ruby

```
sudo apt-get install rubygems1.8 ruby1.8-dev
sudo gem install rubygems-update
sudo gem update rubygems
sudo gem install less
```

Command-line usage

> $ lessc styles.less
>
> $ lessc styles.less > styles.css

or install

```
$ sudo apt-get install node-less yui-compressor
```